# Entry Component Fill the Screen on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to make Entry and Picker fields fill the screen horizontally.

I have tried any possible HorizontalOptions but no success.

My code is as follows;

```xml
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Entry x:Name="ReceiverIBANTextField"  Placeholder="Alıcı IBAN" Keyboard="Numeric">  </Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="ReceiverFullNameTextField"  Placeholder="Alıcı Ad Soyad" >  </Entry>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Entry x:Name="EntryTransferAmount"  Placeholder="Tutar Giriniz" Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Label x:Name="LabelCurrencyName" Text="$" />   
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label TextColor="#0099DC">Tümünü Aktar </Label>
            </StackLayout>                      

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" >
                <Switch x:Name="SwitchForAllInForVirman" Toggled="SwitchForAllIn_Toggled" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
            </StackLayout>                                          
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

            <Entry x:Name="EntryDescriptionForVirman" Placeholder="Açıklama Giriniz"></Entry>           
            <Picker x:Name="PickerPaymentType" Title="Ödeme Tipi" ></Picker>
            <Entry x:Name="QuickTransactionNameTextField"  Placeholder="Hızlı İşlem Adı"></Entry>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>                      
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Try to get screen width and apply to StackLayout then only it will spread. To get screen width you have to write native Android and iOS code.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code in a sample project and you need to also set the `HorizontalOptions` for the second StackLayout to `FillAndExpand` for it to work.